# Can't make Curl POST request from web app

Tags: php, curl

A server I am working on appears to be denying outbound HTTP requests. The reason I think this is because I've tried both `Guzzle` and `curl` requests to the API.

The API lives on the same domain as the web server (this is temporary at clients request). I can make requests to the API server via `Postman` (Chrome plugin), but when I run that same request on the server, it doesn't return anything.

Here are the headers from the 'Postman' request:

```
POST /api2/user/session HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=d9ad79c4c0822fc5c86f4d8799307f1b; _ga=GA1.2.1674422587.1425409444
```

**Post data:**

```
token=a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6&user=30972
```

This works. It returns the data. But when I call the same endpoint from within my web app, I get nothing.

```
$data = urlencode("token=a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6&user=30972");

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/api2/user/session');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What I don't understand is I can run the following, and it returns the content:

```
print file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
```

When I `var_dump` the `$_POST` fields on the endpoint `user/session` it returns the array of postdata using `Postman` but `$_POST` fields are blank when sending via the web app. Even before it makes any request to the database, the post fields should be set right?

Via SSH this also works:

```
curl -F token=a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6 -F user=30972 http://example.com/api2/user/session
```

As suggested in comments I've tried:

```
var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));

// bool(true)
```

I can't figure out what's going on.

**Edit: This works** ... but I don't want to use sockets. Must be a curl issue.

```
$fp = fsockopen('example.com', 80);

$vars = array(
    'token' => 'a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6',
    'user' => '30972'
);
$content = http_build_query($vars);

fwrite($fp, "POST /api2/user/session HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Host: example.com\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

fwrite($fp, $content);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 1024);
}
```

**Edit:**

`curl_error()` also returns no error.

Comment: `curl http://google.com` on the server works :D

Comment: is PHP curl installed. var_dump(function_exists('curl_version')); will show true or false

Comment: Nope bool(true) :( Even more confused now.

Comment: "... I get nothing." No content or what? Do you get any errors? Make sure you have error logging on E_ALL and check the logs...

Comment: var_dump(curl_error($ch));  You seem to not be the only one not being able to reach same domain with curl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand the differences between the PHP code and cURL, I created a RequestBin instance and tried both on it. They yielded drastically different results:

[image: RequestBin]

It seemed like the POST data from the PHP script yielded an incorrect result for what was sent. This can be fixed by using a built-in PHP function [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query).

It will yield a more apt result:

[image: RequestBin with fixed problem]

Comment: Yes this was exactly the problem. Although I answered it, I will accept this because this was the correct solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to use `http_build_query`.

```
$vars = array(
    'token' => 'a559d5bba5a9e9517d5c3ed7aeb62db6',
    'user' => '30972'
);

$content = http_build_query($vars);

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/api2/user/session');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a session lock... If you use curl to access the same server, the same session is used. While the script is running, the session is locked by default, this means that the current request has to finish before another is handled for the same session. This would explain a timeout of the request in curl, as your first request is not completed and another is made...

Using `session_write_close()` before the `curl_exec` will unlock the session and correct the problem.

Comment: Out of interest, the ideal solution to this would be to move the API onto a separate server?  I do plan to do that anyway, but just curious as I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Not necessarily, it all depends on what needs to be done... If the curl request does not need the ssession, you can tell it not to use it. Or if your current script does not need it, close the session as I suggested in my answer